# Batch file conversion and usage

Tags: javascript, python, windows, batch-file

I'm having a problem with a small batch script that I'm writing. The point of the batch script is to run a Javascript file that converts an XML file to a csv file and then run a Python script which will analyze the just created csv file and create another csv file.

The batch script is below.

```
    start XML-CSV_Converter.js
    python CSV_ANALYZER.py
    exit
```

I didn't write the XML-CSV converter;
It can be found here. (http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2011/05/05/excel-batch-convert-xls-to-csv/) The only thing I changed was I removed all of the alerts and input prompts so it doesn't wait on any user input. Simply put, all it does it look at every XML file in the current directory and produces a csv file in the same directory.

Whenever I run the batch script, I keep getting an IO error in my Python script because even though it can see the created file, it isn't able to open the file. 
The exact error is:
 `"IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'NAME_OF_FILE.csv'"`

The part of the Python script which is causing errors is listed below.

```
    dirList = os.listdir("C:\FOLDER")
    for fname in dirList:
        if fname.find(".csv") != -1:
            inputFile = open(fname,'r')     <---- Script halts here
```

Anybody know what could be causing the file not being opened in the Python script?
 If I run the JavaScript file manually, and then the Python script manually, it works perfectly. But when I try to chain them together in a batch file it breaks. I would appreciate any and all ideas! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you verified that the JS script is actually running?

Comment: Yup. It creates the new csv file and I can see it in Windows Explorer after the batch script breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the folder name to the file name in the `open()` call. `listdir()` returns only the file names, so unless its path argument matches the current directory, you'll have to add it to the returned file names to properly identify them.

As a side note, you should also avoid using backward slashes in normal strings. In this case "C:\FOLDER" happens to work, but "C:\folder" wouldn't, because `\f` would be converted to `\x0c` (the linefeed character). You should use either a raw string (`r'C:\FOLDER'` which doesn't convert escaped characters), an escaped backslash (`'C:\\FOLDER'`), or the more portable `'C:/FOLDER'` (on Windows `'/'` is the alternative path separator).

Also a simpler way to check for the extension is to test whether the name ends with it (the `s.find(t) == -1` is not very Pythonic). All in all, the modified code could look something like this:

```
folder = "C:/FOLDER"
for fname in os.listdir(folder):
    if fname.endswith(".csv"):
        inputFile = open(os.path.join(folder, fname),'r')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `start` command launches a program (or, in your case, a file) and immediately returns, without waiting for the program to exit. This means that when Python tries to open the file, the JS script is probably still running and has the file open exclusively for writing.

You should run the JS file by directly calling the Windows Scripting Host (cscript.exe). Just replace the `start` command with:

```
cscript //nologo XML-CSV_Converter.js
```

This will ensure that when the Python command is run, the JS script will have completed its job and safely terminated.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to fix the problem. It still results in the same IOError in the Python script.

Comment: OK, I've added another answer, but I'm also leaving this because it's a common problem that may affect others.

Comment: If `.js` files are associated with `wscript`, you _can` use a `start` command to execute them and just need to add a `/wait` argument before the filename which will start the application and the wait for it to end.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is "python CSV_ANALYZER.py" got executed while the  XML-CSV_Converter.js was not finished.

By type "start XML-CSV_Converter.js", it won't wait for this command to finish before executing the next command.

If you have installed js interpreter, you can remove the `start' in the first line, an then it should work.

Comment: JS files are associated with wscript.exe by default, meaning no output will be sent to the console. That's why I recommend to explicitly use cscript.exe instead.